# Using define macro to overload array access

Tags: c

**Problem.** 
I got a code computing on an array. I am about to define a macro replacing every array reads with a function call. Here is an example:

For this code:

```
sum += a[i];
```

the micro should generate:

```
sum += function_call(a,i);
```

**Current solution.** 
I found that I can replace `a[i]` with `a(i)` and use the following macro:

```
#define a(i) function_call(a,i)
```

However, I prefer not to modify the original code. I just want to add macros.

**Question.** Can I achieve this with a clever macro definition? Any idea is highly appreciated.

Notice: I have to use C syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The C preprocessor doesn't do operator overloading, no matter how clever you are.

The `[]` characters in your input are not inside parentheses, therefore they aren't part of a macro argument, and they aren't alphanumeric characters so they aren't part of a macro name. Anything that's not a macro name or a macro argument is going to be passed through by the preprocessor. The preprocessor doesn't even know that `'['` and `']'` are a matching pair.